# Conjecture---Identity for Sieve of Eratosthenes collisions.

Tags: number-theory

Let

$$\beta(n,k) = \max_{d \leq k}(d|n)$$

$$S(k)= \sum_{n=1}^{k!} \beta(n,k),$$

$\hspace{20mm}$and

$$T(k)=\# \{ ~i\cdot j~~\big|_{i=1}^k \big|_{j=1}^{k!}   \}$$

Does $$S(k)=T(k)?$$

See OEIS [A126959](http://oeis.org/A126959).
Replace $k!$ in $S,T$ with $\exp (\psi(k) )$, where $\psi(\cdot)$ is second Chebyshev function, to get [A101459](http://oeis.org/A101459).

Comment: What is T(n,k)?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas It usually denotes the number of elements in the set.

Comment: For which values of $k$ have you verified that $S(k)=T(k)$?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A126959 has been calculated out to $n=36$, so you have verified $S(k)=T(K)$ out to $k=36$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, One sequence fails at $k=10$ and the other at $k=17$. Yikes!